# How to check http 200 status code in angular if its not available in the json response

Tags: angular

Auth Service

```
 logout() {
      return this.http.post(this.logOutApi, null);
    }
```

The status code doesn't show in the json response from the back end but is shows on postman's status. How to get the status code.

ts file

```
logout() {
    this.chk.logout().subscribe((res: any)=>{
      if(res.status == 200) //doesnt work{
      console.log(res);
      })
      }
    }, (err)=>{
      alert("There was a problem logging you out");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the option of `{ observe: 'response' }` to [read the full response](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response) including the status code in the success handler. This would give you access to a response of type [HttpResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse):

Service:

```
logout() {
  // you should consider providing a type
  return this.http.post(this.logOutApi, null, { observe: 'response' });
}
```

Component:

```
logout() {
    this.chk.logout().subscribe(
  (res) => {
    if (res.status == 200) {
      console.log(res);
    }
  }, (err) => {
    alert("There was a problem logging you out");
  });
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: what does it mean 'providing a type'

Comment: typescript will not know the shape of  your returned  object, you have to set the type of the response to make consuming it easier. this.chk.logout<type>() ...

Answer (score 1):

Other than 200 you get the status code in your error block. So here you will have to handle accordingly like below

```
 logout() {
        this.chk.logout().subscribe((res: any)=>{
          if(res.status == 200) //doesnt work{
          console.log(res);
          })
          }
        }, (error)=>{
          if (error.status === 500) {
                alert('Server down please try after some time');
          }
          else if (error.status === 404) {
               alert('Server down. Please try after some time');
         }

        });
    }
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

It comes under `error` callback

```
, (err)=>{
  alert(err.status);
});
```