# HttpErrorResponse when calling .net core method from Angular 8

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, angular8

I'm calling a controller method and returning success if the operation is complete.But i keep getting the following error

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:5000/api/File/create", ok: false, …}headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}status: 200statusText: "OK"url: "http://localhost:5000/api/File/create"ok: falsename: "HttpErrorResponse"message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:5000/api/File/create"error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHtt…, text: "success"}__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

---

```
[HttpPost("create")]
        public ActionResult<File> Create([FromBody]File file)
        {
            _fileService.Create(file);

            return Ok("success");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an opened issue and you have many solutions:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18396

The best way is to change the responseType:

`this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'text'})`

This is the reference: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54879401/13292987 check this answer...Also you can try to implement an Angular-Interceptor to handle every api response error, check this article: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-angular-interceptors-to-manage-http-requests-and-error-handling and the github sample code: https://github.com/vigneshsithirai/Angular-Interceptor

Answer (score 1):

The Angular side expects a JSON, the called action method in your example returns a plain text string.
For example returning this way the client side will get a JSON and it will be able to parse it:

```
[HttpPost("create")]
public ActionResult<string> Create([FromBody]File file)
{
    _fileService.Create(file);
    return Ok(new { str="success" });
}
```