# Checking if response is 200 from HTTP POST request

Tags: angular, angular8

HttpErrorResponse is 200, but the 'sucess' message never prints. Instead this shows up in the console:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:5000/api/File/create", ok: false, …}
```

```
this.http.post('api/File/create', waldo, { observe: 'response' }).subscribe(data => {
    if (data.status == 200) {
        console.log("success");
    }
});
```

Update:
[image]

Update2:

```
 [HttpPost("create")]
        public ActionResult<File> Create([FromBody]File file)
        {
            try
            {
                _fileService.Create(file);
                return Ok("sucess");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }



        }
```

Comment: And if you pass the second callback to `subscribe`, does it end up there? Do you have any interceptors that might be interfering with the request?

Comment: @jonrsharpe dont know how to do that.. i just started with angular 8

Comment: How to do what? Pass a callback? You're already passing the first, `data => ...`. Have a look at e.g. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Observable#subscribe to see the various things you can pass.

Comment: How does `console.log(data)` look like on the console before the `if` statement?

Comment: @tenkmilan the breakpoint never reaches there... please see the update

Comment: I see, could you please add to the `subscribe` method an error handler as well. I mean followings:
`.subscribe(data => {
    if (data.status == 200) {
        console.log("success");
    }
}, err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err));`
Do you see the error message of the observer on the console using the above code snippet?

Comment: @tenkmilan Yes... there is an error `product.component.ts:111 Observer got an error: [object Object]`

Comment: @tenkmilan i'm passing an object to the post method..

Comment: Yes, the first parameter is the route, the second is the body of the post request and the third is an option, what the observer should subscribe to. What happens if you give it a try without `{observe: 'response'}` parameter?

Comment: @tenkmilan same issue...

Comment: Hm.. How does the `err` object look like, if you change the `console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err));` snippet to `{console.error('Observer got an error:'); console.error(err);}`?

Comment: @tenkmilan `message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:5000/api/File/create"
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: "sucess"}`

Comment: @tenkmilan Please see update 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular side expects by default a JSON response. The endpoint does not respond a JSON object, it responds a plain text. The Angular side tries to parse the plain text as JSON but it is not able to do it, this is why an error is thrown.

There are 2 ways to handle this issue:

On server side a JSON has to be returned [as answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61168850/httperrorresponse-when-calling-net-core-method-from-angular-8/61169704#61169704).

Or the http client on Angular side should be configured to expect plain text.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's because your create API does not return json.

Try specifying `responseType` in the request options so that angular does not try to parse the response content as a json object:

```
this.http.post('api/File/create', waldo, { observe: 'response', responseType: 'text' })
```